# Looking for rest parameter for copy/create document with content for post method

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, file, flow

We are trying to copy document from SharePoint Online document library to documentum(DCTM) repository using REST API (MS-Flow).

Right now we are able to create document to documentum(DCTM) with properties but file copy/created with 0 KB. we are unable to copy file content, Can anyone please suggest which parameter we are missing for copy file content in body.

```
{"properties":{"r_object_type": "pet_document", "object_name": "@{triggerBody()?['{Name}']}","physical_location" : "@{triggerBody()?['PrimaryLocation']}"}} "file" : @{body('Get_file_content')}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screen shot or code snippet of file creation block

Comment: Hi Sunil, Please find attached screen shot for your reference

Comment: Hi, this will likely get flagged for being off-topic as the issue is with a 3rd party.

Comment: Hi James, Yes, we are just expecting or rather checking with people that we are giving correct header and body as we are able to copy/create file with metadata but unable to copy file content

Comment: Why don't you use 'create a file' action from MS Flow